# Regex escape multiple quotation

Tags: python, sed

I have bunch of crawled endpoint result from a domain, it was parsed in Json format. I've successfully aggregate the json to extract it's endpoint using sed and I wanted to merge all the sed command into my python crawl script. Here's the crawl output :

```
{'Results': [{'Result': {'IsDB': 'True', 'Spend': 367, 'Paths': [{'Technologies': [{'Categories': ['Japan hosting'], 'Name': 'Internet Initiative Japan','Link': 'https://www.iij.ad.jp'},{'Name': 'GlobalSign Domain Verification', 'Link': 'https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/2167245-performing-domain-verification---dns-txt-record'}]}]}]}
```

The reason why I use regex instead of `jq` to resolve the json is: sometimes the json has `invalid` format and the single-quotation `' '` raises other exception.

The problem is; I had to use `os` module to execute `bash` command which the sed command itself has inner quotation. Here's the implementation:

```
temp = "testi.txt"
os.system(f"sed -i 's/http:\/\//\nhttp:\/\//g' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i 's/https:\/\//\nhttps:\/\//g' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i 's/Tag/\\nTag/g' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i '/Tag/d' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i '/Result/d' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i 's/\', \'*$//' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i 's/^http:\/\///' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i 's/^https:\/\///' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i 's/\/.*//' {temp}")
```

As expected these 3 sed command are breaker, resulting in yet another mess:

```
os.system(f"sed -i 's/http:\/\//\nhttp:\/\//g' {temp}")
os.system(f"sed -i 's/https:\/\//\nhttps:\/\//g' {temp}") 
os.system(f"sed -i 's/\', \'*$//' {temp}")
```

I have tried to escape the newline Unicode `\n` and inner quotation `', '` with double backslash but didn't work.

```
's/http:\/\//\\nhttp:\/\//g'
's/https:\/\//\\nhttps:\/\//g' 
's/\\', \\'*$//'
```

Another reason to use sed is because; the target file has multi-lines inside, so I thought it was more easy to use sed instead of read each line using python. Any help would be cherished...

Comment: Python is perfectly capable of performing string substututions without the help of `sed`. (If you wanted to use `sed`, at least combine all these commands into a single script, rather than piping a string of processes.)

Comment: _"sometimes the json has invalid format"_ - then, the only thing I'd use `sed` for is to correct the invalid format. Then use `jq` or `python` directly to parse it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: trickier than it seems. For instance, some of the string values contain apostrophes (and are therefore in the correct double quotes instead of single quotes), so a simple s/'/"/g won't work.

Comment: @MarkReed Oh. In that case, I'd go to the source of the problem, the suppliers of the broken json, and demand that they fix it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking simply for

```
import re
urls = re.findall(r'(?<=")https?://[^"]+(?=")', text)
```

Your sample shows single quotes but real JSON uses double quotes, so I assumed you sample shows how Python parsed it. If your broken JSON really has single quotes instead of double, swap them around in the code.

```
urls = re.findall(r"(?<=')https?://[^']+(?=')", text)
```

You'd obviously have the pseudo-JSON as a string in `text`.

Comment: It definitely makes more sense to use Python's own capabilities than to shell out from Python to sed. But the real problem is that what the endpoint is returning is not valid JSON, which you should report to whoever's responsible for it so they can fix it.

Comment: Didn't work, it returns an empty list ```[]```. Probably i got to mention that the json is invalid at most time @tripleee

Comment: That doesn't matter, the regex just pulls out text which looks like URLs between double quotes. It's unclear where the broken JSON is coming from and whether that part is at all related to Python. but you'd put that in `text` with line feeds and all. (Your sample shows single quotes, but I assumed the real data has double quotes; if not, it should be obvious what to change.)